# MySQL query - latest month/year

Tags: mysql, datetime

My SQL isn't the greatest, obviously, but what I'm trying to do is get the latest date in a database by finding the maximum year and month in an entry. Right now I have:

```
select max(Month), max(Year) from posts where postID = 25;
```

...but that results in the latest month and the latest year, though they're not part of the same entry. How can I make sure month and year are from one entry and not separate?

Comment: Well, you're obviously no oracle. :)

Comment: you have chosen a wrong data type, where you should combine year+month+day into DATE field instead separate into year,month

Comment: @ajreal - I completely agree, you should use the datatypes for what they are made for!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into changing it into a DATE field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT Month, Year FROM posts WHERE postID = 25 ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC LIMIT 1`